# Trying to migrate old code to null safety with a custom MyMenu widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I made a custom MyMenu widget containing: title, imageUrl, shape, and page. The logic is that if there is no image available, an icon should be the default.

```
    class MyMenu extends StatelessWidget {
    MyMenu({this.title, this.icon, this.shape, this.page, this.imageUrl = ''}) {
    if (icon != null) {
      assert(imageUrl == null || imageUrl.isEmpty);
    } else if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.isEmpty) {
      assert(icon == null);
    }
   }

  final page;
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final String imageUrl;
  final MaterialColor shape;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page),
        ),
        splashColor: Colors.amberAccent,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Visibility(
                visible: icon != null && imageUrl.isEmpty,
                child: Icon(
                  icon,
                  size: 80.0,
                  color: shape,
                ),
                replacement: Image.asset(
                  imageUrl,
                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(child: Text(title, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0)))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}






class Menus extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        children: <Widget>[
          MyMenu(
            title: "Sony",
            imageUrl: 'assets/images/sony.png',
            shape: Colors.brown,
            page: SonyPage(),
          ),
          MyMenu(
            title: "Panasonic",
            imageUrl: 'assets/images/panasonic.png',
            shape: Colors.grey,
            page: PanasonicPage2(),
          ),
    ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error: The parameter 'title, icon & shape' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
When I add 'required', then I get a problem with the icon as it is not actually required in the 'Menus' class.

- When I add default values, other problems start coming up. I need help with a better way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of your whole null logic. Try making variables null-safe simply by adding "?" example String? title;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, add `required` to all the fields except icon. like this:

```
MyMenu({required this.title, this.icon,required this.shape,required this.page, this.imageUrl = ''})
```

and now while declaring, make the icon nullable.

```
final page;
final String title;
final IconData? icon;  // <-- make this change
final String imageUrl;
final MaterialColor shape;
```